# Are you able to attack a dark elixir storage without own elixir storage?

Tags: clash-of-clans

are you able to attack an enemy's dark elixir storage without your own dark elixir storage to hold the stolen resource?

Furthermore if you are able to attack it what consequences occur.

Comment: i asked this 6 months ago.. the other person asked this 2 months ago. Are you guys serious? You mark this as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: Older duplicates are not immune to closure.  Whichever has the better answers is the one that we keep open, so that it can get even better answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can attack the enemy's dark elixir storage.  However, if you don't have your own dark elixir storage, you won't be able to keep the dark elixir gained from the battle.

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the Dark Elixir storage/collector, at the end of the battle it will say how much dark elixir you stole, but it won't give the Dark elixir to you