# How is dark elixir distributed among storage buildings?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am a Town Hall level 7 and have a Dark Elixir drill but no DE storage yet. I have collected 2k DE until so far.

Now I am about to build a DE storage which can hold 6000. I need 10k Dark Elixir for the Barbarian King. My present DE, the 2k DE my DE drill has generated, is stored in the Town Hall. If I build a storage, will this DE stay in the TH or will it be transferred to the storage?

[image: screenshot of stored resources in Town Hall]

Answer (score 1):

Once you build a DE storage, all your stored Dark Elixir, except those in the [Clan Castle (Treasury)](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Treasury), will be…

> …split between the Dark Elixir Storage and the Town Hall in a 4:1 ratio, which means that the Dark Elixir available from the Dark Elixir Storage itself is four times greater than that available from the Town Hall.

Source: Clash of Clans Wiki, "[Raids - Dark Elixir](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids#Dark_Elixir)" article.

Answer (score 0):

Dark Elixir is not stored anywhere until you have a dark elixir storage.
Reference : http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Resources#Dark_Elixir
So I'm sorry to say, but your dark elixir has probably been lost.

Edit: Apparently I overlooked this section : http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall
At the resources available section, it shows that TH7 can store 2500 dark elixir. The dark elixir should be safe, the TH acts as a secondary storage, no dark elixir should be transferred.

Comment: But TH 7 does show 2500 DE storage. It shouldnot be lost...

Comment: Where are you reading that? The elixir you raid from town halls doesn't mean that the enemy actually has elixir stored in their town hall. Another question has this answer : [link] http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/are-you-able-to-attack-a-dark-elixir-storage-without-own-elixir-storage?rq=1

Comment: When i click my TH , it shows it has de storage in it. I ll upload a pic here.. Wait...

Comment: So 2.5 k DE will be safe right?

Comment: It should be... odd, I've never remembered seeing this when I played Clash of Clans.